# Searching for a sliding menu compatible with IE8

Tags: jquery, menu

Can I have help please. I'm searching since many days a sliding menu compatible with IE8 like that : http://alizahid.github.io/jquery-sliding-menu/

This one is not compatible with IE8 can I have help please. Someone know an equivalent compatible with IE8 ?

Comment: Try including `es5-shim.js` (https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) and see if that helps.  You may or may not also need `html5shiv.js` (https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv).

Comment: Also make sure you're using an IE8-compatible version of jQuery (that's the 1.x line).

Comment: @RocketHazmat thank you for your help. I go home and I try. I use jquery 1.11.3 it's ok ?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.  jQuery 2 doesn't work with IE 8, but jQuery 1.11.x does.

Comment: P.S. You can get the 2 shims from https://cdnjs.com/.  https://cdnjs.com/libraries/es5-shim (es5-shim.min.js) and https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html5shiv (html5shiv.min.js).  If you are doing anything with old, crappy versions of IE, then you probably want to include these shims.

Comment: Unfortunately that don't work :-(

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://output.jsbin.com/xiqotukezu/1 (edit at http://jsbin.com/xiqotukezu/1/edit?html,js)

Comment: You might want to edit `jquery-sliding-menu.css` and change the `'\3009'` and `'\3008'` to `'>'` and `'<'`, respectively.  I don't think IE8 likes unicode characters very much.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Your Output.jsbin permit to know if it's compatible with IE8 ?

Comment: Can you reword that, I'm not sure what you're asking me?

Comment: I wanted to know how you know it's compatible with IE8 ? It's possible to know that with your JSBIN ?

Comment: I have a Windows XP VM installed.  I know it works in IE8 because I opened http://output.jsbin.com/xiqotukezu/1 in IE8.  (P.S. You can get free VMs for testing things in IE from: https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/)

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I think that I have a problem with a JS file on the site that I created. Something who prevents the script to be well executed. A conflict. Because I got a problem with my bootstrap (3.3.5) grid too. I use respond.js and html5shiv.js but my grid is totally broken... I'm totally lost. I spend 2 weeks on the website and nothing run under IE8

Comment: Do you *really* need it to work with IE8?  Also, this sounds like a *new* question.

Comment: Unfortunately yes :-( because this is for a client who ask me an IE8 compatibility. It's just horrible... I tested the site with VitualBox

Comment: Well, `es5-shim.js` seems to fix the sliding menu you asked about in this question.  If you have other issues, I'd suggest making a new question.  Try to make a small example of each issue and hopefully we can help fix it.

Comment: You seem to be trying to load jQuery UI *before* jQuery.  Check the order of your scripts.  P.S. Chrome also throws a few errors in its console on your site.

Comment: Try to use IE8's (crappy, but at least existent) dev tools (`F12`) to see the errors on your page.

Comment: Ok I deleted jQuery UI because I didn't use it. And I resolved an error about "openhand.cur". I used dev tools for that

Comment: Do you have any info you can add (possibly to the question itself)?  Are there any messages in the console?  Try to open the the console, then reload the page.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't have messages in the console now. All it's clean.